# How to diagnose a generalized linear mixed model?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, panel-data

I am fitting a generalized linear mixed model for a binary outcome using SAS with two random intercepts, one for the repeated measures and one for the household clustering.

What are the appropriate diagnostics I can do to check the assumptions and the goodness of fit of my model?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234998/logistic-regression-diagnostic-plots-in-r https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234998/logistic-regression-diagnostic-plots-in-r and for random effects https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77101/what-diagnostics-for-random-effects-logistic-regression https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74251/generalized-linear-mixed-models-diagnostics

Comment: Which assumptions are you interested in ?

Comment: All of the logistic regression assumptions.