# Assessing the fit of GLMM implementation of a Rasch model to binary data using lme4

Tags: residuals, glmm, binary-data, lme4-nlme, rasch

I'd like to assess the fit of the kinds of models described by de Boeck et al (2011) (http://www.jstatsoft.org/v39/i12). They are GLMM implementations of Rasch family models, e.g.:

```
all.1.NULL.Rasch <- glmer(score ~ -1 
                          + item
                          + (-1 + X064.part.Part | person), data = IN11c, family=binomial)
```

As Gelman and Hill (2006) explain, a binned residual plot is a better approach than simply plotting the fitted values against the residuals (also discussed here: [How to assess the fit of a binomial GLMM fitted with lme4 (> 1.0)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70783/how-to-assess-the-fit-of-a-binomial-glmm-fitted-with-lme4-1-0)).

However, my plots (using the arm package) exhibit a striking pattern, which seems to me likely to be due to some aspect of the model which is different from those Gelman and Hill were talking about.

[image]

Can anyone explain this, and, preferably also a useful way to assess the fit of the type of model I have?

First, I'm assuming that this is correct:

```
binnedplot(fitted(all.1.NULL.Rasch),residuals(all.1.NULL.Rasch))
```

The data actually has 89 variables, so I'm supplying details for those in the quoted model:

```
> str(IN11c$score)
 Ord.factor w/ 2 levels "0"<"1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

> str(IN11c$X064.part.Part)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> str(IN11c$person)
 Factor w/ 9961 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

> summary(IN11c$score)
     0      1   NA's 
109222 238188   1225 

> summary(IN11c$X064.part.Part)
     1      2      3      4 
 69727  79688  69727 129493 

> summary(IN11c$person)
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10      11      12      13      14      15 
 35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35 
 16      17      18      19      20      21      22      23      24      25      26      27      28      29      30 
 35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35 
 31      32      33      34      35      36      37      38      39      40      41      42      43      44      45 
 35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35 
 46      47      48      49      50      51      52      53      54      55      56      57      58      59      60 
 35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35 
 61      62      63      64      65      66      67      68      69      70      71      72      73      74      75 
 35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35 
 76      77      78      79      80      81      82      83      84      85      86      87      88      89      90 
 35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35 
 91      92      93      94      95      96      97      98      99 (Other) 
 35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35      35  345170
```

and the output:

```
> summary(all.1.NULL.Rasch)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation)  ['glmerMod']

Family: binomial  ( logit )

Formula: score ~ -1 + item + (-1 + X064.part.Part | person)
Data: IN11c

  AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
369799.0  370283.1 -184854.5  369709.0    347365 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.4212 -0.6800  0.3506  0.5897  6.6114 

Random effects:
Groups Name            Variance Std.Dev. Corr          
person X064.part.Part1 2.2550   1.5017                 
    X064.part.Part2 0.7472   0.8644   0.71          
    X064.part.Part3 2.4486   1.5648   0.54 0.75     
    X064.part.Part4 0.7124   0.8441   0.63 0.86 0.69
Number of obs: 347410, groups:  person, 9961

Fixed effects:
    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
itemX1   3.01316    0.04289   70.25  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX2  -0.60039    0.02900  -20.71  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX3   2.06994    0.03466   59.72  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX4   0.05922    0.02830    2.09  0.03635 *  
itemX5   2.69565    0.03966   67.96  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX6   1.67934    0.03239   51.85  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX7   2.27617    0.03612   63.02  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX8   1.61074    0.02833   56.86  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX9   0.60380    0.02391   25.26  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX10  0.46635    0.02362   19.74  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX11  1.60557    0.02830   56.73  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX12  0.63788    0.02398   26.60  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX13  0.87095    0.02463   35.36  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX14  1.20185    0.02602   46.18  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX15  0.92694    0.02484   37.32  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX16  0.30951    0.02872   10.78  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX17 -0.08539    0.02869   -2.98  0.00292 **  
itemX18  0.13537    0.02866    4.72 2.32e-06 ***  
itemX19  1.34097    0.03091   43.39  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX20  1.03142    0.03000   34.38  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX21  0.91493    0.02967   30.84  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX22 -0.14124    0.02874   -4.91 8.94e-07 ***  
itemX23 -0.36678    0.02346  -15.63  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX24  1.89063    0.03027   62.45  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX25  2.38406    0.03510   67.93  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX26  1.06347    0.02527   42.08  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX27  0.59852    0.02378   25.17  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX28  0.38406    0.02341   16.40  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX29  1.43106    0.02709   52.83  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX30  1.22191    0.02600   46.99  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX31  0.97085    0.02489   39.00  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX32  1.16746    0.02568   45.46  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX33 -0.06049    0.02322   -2.60  0.00919 **  
itemX34  0.44368    0.02351   18.87  < 2e-16 ***  
itemX35  1.65890    0.02853   58.15  < 2e-16 ***
```

Comment: certainly interesting.  Any chance we could see `str(IN11c)` or `summary(IN11c)` and/or relevant bits of `summary(all.1.NULL.Rasch)` ?

Answer (score 2):

OK, the only thing I can think of (in the absence of any continuous predictors) is link misspecification.  Tried this using the logit-power link code from [the linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70783/how-to-assess-the-fit-of-a-binomial-glmm-fitted-with-lme4-1-0), but I can't actually get it to look like your data (it's much noisier).

Logit-power (uses (fragile) internal C calls for speed; could use `plogis()`, `qlogis()` for readability and stability instead)

```
logitpower <- function(lambda) {
    L <- list(linkfun=function(mu)
              .Call(stats:::C_logit_link,mu^(1/lambda),PACKAGE="stats"),
              linkinv=function(eta)
              .Call(stats:::C_logit_linkinv,eta,PACKAGE="stats")^lambda,
              mu.eta=function(eta) {
                  mu <-  .Call(stats:::C_logit_linkinv,eta,PACKAGE="stats")
                  mu.eta <-  .Call(stats:::C_logit_mu_eta,eta,PACKAGE="stats")
                  lambda*mu^(lambda-1)*mu.eta
              },
              valideta = function(eta) TRUE ,
              name=paste0("logit-power(",lambda,")"))
    class(L) <- "link-glm"
    L
}
```

Comparing the shape of logit-power links, tweaked to have approximately
the same x-intercept:

```
par(las=1,bty="l")
curve(logitpower(1)$linkinv(x),from=-4,to=4)
curve(logitpower(0.5)$linkinv(x-1),add=TRUE,col=2)
curve(logitpower(2)$linkinv(x+0.8),add=TRUE,col=4)
legend("bottomright",bty="n",lty=1,col=c(1,2,4),
       paste0("lambda=",c(1,0.5,2)))
abline(v=0,lty=2)
```

[image]

This suggests that the pattern observed above (underpredict for values < 0.5, overpredict for values > 0.5) could come from a logit-power link with $\lambda>1$

However, when we try simulating and fitting with regular logit and logit-power links, it doesn't reproduce your pattern (and doesn't seem to make much difference):

```
ff <- binomial(link=logitpower(4))
dd <- expand.grid(f1=factor(1:10),f2=factor(1:20),rep=1:20)
library("lme4")
betavec <- seq(-2,2,length=10)
dd$y <- simulate(~-1+f1+(1|f2),family=ff,
         newdata=dd,
         newparams=list(theta=1,beta=betavec),
         seed=101)[[1]]
fit1 <- glmer(y~-1+f1+(1|f2),family=ff,
              data=dd)
fit2 <- update(fit1,family=binomial)
```

Binned residual plots:

```
library("arm")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
binnedplot(predict(fit1,type="response"),resid(fit1),nclass=100)
binnedplot(predict(fit2,type="response"),resid(fit2),nclass=100)
```

[image]