# In a random intercept model with a binomial outcome should the predicted probabilities be normally distributed?

Tags: interpretation, random-effects-model

I have fit a random intercept model in glmer and stan_glmer with the following model formula where my event is 0/1 and x1 and x2 are continuous covariates:

```
     model <- stan_glmer(binary event ~ x1 + x2 +(1 | group), family="binomial"
```

The predicted probabilities (i.e. the fitted values from the model) are not normally distributed. Does this mean the model is wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be normally distributed..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for a variety of different reasons.  I can't think of any situation where I would expect the predictions to be Normally distributed. There might be cases where I'd expect the *residuals* to be Normally distributed, but even this is not expected in the Bernoulli (0/1) response case.  For example, see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70783/how-to-assess-the-fit-of-a-binomial-glmm-fitted-with-lme4-1-0/71878#71878) ...